# How to show different type of legend below specific columns under X axis on stacked bar chart

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

I have drawn a stacked column chart in Google sheet. I want to put different legends below specific columns as secondary label under the x-axis; here is my spradesheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqvMD9OpDypMC3SV2Gebhncw5QVpkCi8cx24LGiu4P0/edit?usp=sharing

[attaching a sample graph picture the way I want my graph to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZJCv.png)